# How to get the binarys path to a process without lsof?

Tags: fedora, process

How could I find out what is the path to the binary file from a process? Like:

```
[usern@hostn ~]$ ps aux | grep -i gnome-session
gbor      2844  0.0  0.2  38072  7152 ?        Ssl  05:53   0:00 gnome-session
[usern@hostn ~]$ lsof | grep -i gnome-session
gnome-ses  2844      gbor  txt       REG      253,1   252592     792784 /usr/bin/gnome-session
[usern@hostn ~]$
```

Without using "lsof"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/proc/<PID>/exe` is a symlink to the process's executable.

Comment: Pointing out **`readlink /proc/<PID>/exe`** before anyone tries to parse the hell out of `ls` output.